# I added another SSD and the boot time is significantly longer. Why is this?

Tags: boot, ssd

I have a Dell Latitude 5520 laptop which came with an NVMe KBG40ZNS256G NVMe KIOXIA 256GB SSD. I experienced very short boot times - around a couple of seconds. However, I added a spare SSD, a TOSHIBA KSG60ZMV256G M.2 2280 256GB SSD. In order to do this, I had to move the first SSD to the second slot on the motherboard and place the Toshiba SSD in the first slot. This is because the second slot is only compatible with PCI 4.0 SSDs, while the Toshiba is a SATA SSD. Upon starting up, I noticed a very long boot time, which took a couple of minutes. I booted multiple times in order to make sure that this was not a one-off occurrence. I also used disk manager and noticed a system reserved section had been created in the Toshiba SSD. I tried deleting this, as I thought this long boot time was due to the computer attempting to boot from the Toshiba SSD. The boot time was around the same. I also tried to use the one-time boot menu by pressing f12 and then selecting to boot from the Kioxia drive. This caused no notable change to the boot time. As a final test, I tried removing the Toshiba SSD entirely and booting with only my Kioxia SSD in the second slot. The laptop booted quickly, around the same speed as when it was in the first slot.

It seems that simply having the Toshiba SSD plugged into the motherboard significantly slows the boot time. I noted that only the boot time was affected. All of the computer's other functions were unaffected. In fact, I am typing this right now with both SSDs plugged in and don't notice any difference. Could anyone offer a possible explanation for why this is happening?

Comment: Sounds like a UEFI firmware bug

Comment: @TomYan In what way would it be bugged for this to happen?

Comment: In so many ways that even a short list wouldn't fit a comment here. So, the obvious suggestion is to update UEFI before anything else. Then the SSDs themselves might need a firmware update too. Lastly, make sure the drive priority is set to the one that contains the ESP (EFI System Partition) to avoid unnecessary delay (UEFI > Boot and then look for a drive order setting, not the boot order by itself).

Comment: What is "boot time"?? What is happening, what is on screen?

Comment: @mitts with both SSDs the Dell logo appears.  After a couple of minutes, a rotating loading ring appears and the OS starts up. When I only had the Kioxia SSD the rotating loading ring would appear almost instantly and the OS would load within seconds.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I have just tried updating the firmware for both drives. Both updates failed on account that they were already up to the latest version. I will start to look at any possible issues with UEFI now.

Comment: @ChanganAuto You should post your comment as an actual answer since the original poster has now [posted an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1721764/167207) referencing your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to ChanganAuto for the solution. Updating BIOS/UEFI through a remote flash update from 1.13.0 to 1.18.1 solved the problem. Now boot times are almost the same speed as before without any issues.

Comment: To be fair, ChanganAuto should post their comment as an answer here so they can get the credit for an answer.

Comment: If ChanganAuto does decide to do so I will delete this answer and mark theirs as the solution.